# Latest Chrome updates causes linear-gradient backgrounds with multiple colors to behave differently

Tags: css

This is hard to put into words, but I think the [codepen](http://codepen.io/lowbelly/pen/xEvxbx) makes the issue clear.

I'm using a method to create a background with multiple colored, sharply defined (no blur) diagonal colors with linear-gradient. However, with the latest release of Chrome (Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)), instead of sharp edges, there is a blur separating the sections. The technique continues to work as expected in Safari, Firefox, and Edge.

```
background: linear-gradient(120deg, 
    #666 50%, 
    #212531 50%,
    #212531 60%,
    #333 60%
);
```

I've also submitted a bug because this problem only arose with the latest release. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660891

Does anyone have a workaround? I'm not confident that it will be resolved by Chrome in a timely fashion.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I am on the Chrome v56 dev build and it doesn't show the blur that I can see in your image (attached in the bug thread). It is giving the usual sharp edge output.